# Pandas get max ID in rows and add to empty rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to automatically add ID# to every row in a pandas dataframe.

example:

```
   ID Ticker
0   0   AAPL
1   0   TSLA
2   0   GOOG
```

The 'ID' column should automatically be filled in like this:

output:

```
   ID Ticker
0   1   AAPL
1   2   TSLA
2   3   GOOG
```

I am having issues achieving this though. I tried multiple things, including making a function to iterate over every row, but so far I am having issues with this seemingly simple task. I was hoping someone on here could help me out to achieve this.

sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [0, 0, 0],
                'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GOOG']})
print(df1)

output = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3],
                'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GOOG']})

print(output)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
df['ID'] = df.index + 1
```

By doing this, the value of index + 1 is added in ID column, if your `index` is correctly in order

Comment: I'm assuming each ticker might appear more than once and should have the same ID

Answer (score 1):

This will give each ticker a unique numeric id

```
df1['ID'] = df1['Ticker'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I do not need to categories the tickers by ID number, but thank you for thinking along and adding this to the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [0, 0, 0],
                'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GOOG']})

df1.ID = [x for x in range(1, len(df1.values)+1)]

print(df1)
```

```
   ID Ticker
0   1   AAPL
1   2   TSLA
2   3   GOOG
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.